# Python Postgres how to insert

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test1' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='123'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO product_info (product_name) VALUES (%s)""", 'xxx')
except:
    print "error happens"
```

The above is my code snippet, I have no trouble connecting to the database, but I have some problem inserting the value into it.

I execute the same query in postgres and it works, so i think it's a syntax problem.

Can someone show me what is the right way to do insertion?

Comment: still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cur.execute("""
    insert into product_info (product_name) VALUES (%s)
""", ('xxx',))
conn.commit()
```

Notice that the value is passed to the method wrapped in an iterable.